# How to show full field for Bootstrap input date fields?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, input

When I use Boostrap to create a date `input` field that has a limited width

```
<input type="date" id="my_date" name="my_date" class="form-control" style="width:80px">
```

the value (or the placeholder) are covered by the control icons when the field is focused; fine. But when the field is not focused, the place where the control icons are placed if focused takes white space.

[image: Bootstrap date input field examples]

Is there a workaround so that the field shows full content if not focused?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. When you hover the buttons are displayed. If the text is still hidden, try to make a smaller font, or less padding.

**CSS**

```
#my_date::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  display: none;
}
#my_date:hover::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  display: block;
}
```